# Find: $\lim_{n→ +\infty} \lim_{x→0^+} f^{(n)}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$f(x)= e^{\sqrt{x}} + e^{-\sqrt{x}}$
$$\lim_{n +\infty}  \lim_{x→0^+} f^{(n)}(x)$$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. My first thought was that the answer was $+\infty$, but that is not correct.

Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The function is not defined for $x<0$? How can you take limit from the left at $0$?

Comment: I took the problem from a textbook of problems. The symbol they used was a arrow that was pointing downwards to 0. I interpreted that as $ x->0^{-1}$. I will change the text in the question from  0$^{-1} $to 0. Sorry.

Comment: No, arrow pointing downward to $0$ means that $x$ approaches $0$ from *above*, so this should be $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. I usually use a different notation for x aproaching 0 from above/below. I will change the question accordingly!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is function is still well defined and purely real for $x<0$

Comment: @Hynnes Does $f^{(n)}$ signify the $n$-th derivative of $f$ or function composition $n$ times?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I was aware of that. But from the context and the tag 'Real anaysis' I thought there was  a typo in the question.

Comment: @bjorn93 I think it signifies the n-th derivative of f

Answer (score 1):

We can use that

$$e^{\sqrt{x}}+e^{-\sqrt{x}} = 2\cosh\sqrt{x}$$

And that

$$\cosh x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \implies 2\cosh \sqrt{x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{k}}{(2k)!}$$

To get from Taylor's  theorem

$$(\cosh\sqrt{0})^{(n)} = \frac{2\cdot n!}{(2n)!} \to 0$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain how is cosh(x) different from cos(x) or you could tell me where I could learn more about it? I've never heard of cosh before.

Comment: Instead of using $\cosh$, you could just use the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$.